# Catching verilog input nets by using python regex (hierarchical split by 1."()", 2."{}", 3."," )

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm wondering if I can split python string by 3 steps

First by (), secondly by {}, and finally by ","

```
string = "module ( a , b, c, d, {e, f, g}, {h,i}, j, k )"  

result = re.split("",string)  
print(result)
```

I want this code's result to be as below

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '{e,f,g}', '{h,i}', 'j', 'k']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify your question a little bit? What patterns have you tried? The pattern you show in the example code is completely empty, which isn't going to do much for you! Are you sure regular expressions are the right tool for this job? Regular expressions are (in their pure forms) limited to matching a regular language, and your problem seems like it might be beyond that (with the possibly nested matching brackets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you ask, if things aren't nested any more deeply than this.

```
import re
pat = r'\w+|{[^}]*}'
string = "module ( a , b, c, d, {e, f, g}, {h,i}, j, k )"  
result = re.findall(pat, string)
print(list(result))
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
['module', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '{e, f, g}', '{h,i}', 'j', 'k']
```